# Why are my xbees lost data?

Tags: xbee, packets

Here is my case:
    I have 3 xbees, and i use two of them to send messages to the third one.
    I make a loop to send two messages per sec and each message is about 50 bytes.
    when i use the third xbee to receive the messages , i received only part of them .I'm sure that all messages send out

successfully.
    E.g, i send out about 107 messages of each xbee, which means total 214 messages. but on the third xbee , i only received 98

messages from the first xbee and 91 messages from the second xbee.

Q:
   1. it seems that all messages have sent out , so it must be the receiver's fault, is it because of receive buffer size or

something?
   2, I should use at least 3 xbees to send packets and i have only 1 receiver, so how do i do to solve the problem?
   Plus: My xbee is S1 pro, and i can not use other version or update firmware.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're running at 115200 bps on your XBee radios instead of 9600 bps.

Make sure you're using unicast messages (messages addressed directly to the device) instead of broadcast messages.  On a ZigBee network, broadcasts are re-sent 3 times by every router on the network and result in a lot of network traffic.

Comment: I indeed use unicast messages , but my XBee radios is 9600 bps. Why should i have to use  the 115200 bps? I thought it just need running at the same radios between XBees.Plus, the supplier explain that one xbee can receive 12 other senders at one time and without any lost.

Comment: XBee radios send at 250,000bps.  Changing the transfer rate of the serial connection between the XBee module and the host reduces the amount of buffering necessary on the XBee, and reduces the amount of time it takes to send/receive data.